# sapui5 read key value pairs from properties file

Tags: javascript, sapui5

im searching for a way to read key value pairs from a properties file like: `model=Ford`.
For the i18n there are `sap.ui.model.resource.ResourceModel` but i thing it is only for the language translation. 
I will access the data in my xml View like: `{car>model}`.
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have an own properties file and read from it

```
var oBundle = new sap.ui.model.resource.ResourceModel({
    bundleUrl: "/example/cars.properties"
});
var myFord = oBundle.getText("model"),
```

But from your last sentence, i believe that -in reality- you are in need for an JSON-Model.

[Walkthrough Step 7: JSON-Models](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/70ef981d350a495b940640801701c409.html)

[Sap UI5 with Local JSON Model](https://blogs.sap.com/2014/12/10/sap-ui5-with-local-json-model/)